# Conservative force and its Potential Energy Function

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, potential-energy

We are given that $\vec{F}=k\left<y,x,0\right>$, and asked whether $\vec{F}$ is a conservative force. If yes, we are asked to find $U(x,y,z)$ and then find $\vec{F}$ back from $U$ and show it matches the original form.

Given $\vec{\nabla} \times\vec{F}=\vec{0}$, force is conservative.

Therefore, $U(x,y,z)=-\int_{r_0}^r \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}=-\int_0^x kydx-\int_0^y kxdy=-2xyk.$ (Note that the $z$ component is $0$).

Such a potential function yields $\vec{F}=-\vec{\nabla}U=2k\left<y,x,0\right>.$

Something must be wrong or I must be missing something because I get an extra factor of 2 and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you integrated it the wrong way. 

 $$\int ky \, dx  + \int kx \, dy = \int k \,d(xy) $$ 

X and y are not independent.

Comment: I am not quite following... . How are those two equivalent?

Comment: Xdy +ydx= d(xy) .. Refer differential equations for better understanding

Comment: So you're invoking the product rule?

Comment: It'd be nice if you could elaborate a bit. Like why aren't $x$ and $y$ independent of one another? How do you combine the two integrals? etc.

Comment: Your doubt here is primarily on differential equation and its solution, look it up. If you have a doubt on that, then ask

Comment: I understand the math! What I don't get right now is why I cannot take the integrals on the left hand side individually. That is, why do I have to write them in terms of one integral (the one on the right) to evaluate them. Is it because x and y are dependent on each other? If so, then WHY are the dependent?